# L'espressione 'a fortiori' è italiana o latina?

Tags: latin

Ci sono alcune espressioni o parole latine comunemente usate nella lingua italiana, per esempio 'in vino veritas' e 'deficit'.

Capisco che 'in vino veritas', strettamente parlando, sia un'espressione latina, ma sono meno sicuro di 'deficit'.

Cioè, non sono sicuro che 'deficit' possa strettamente considerarsi, ancora oggi, un parola latina piuttosto che italiana.

Però è l'espressione 'a fortiori' che, sotto il suddetto aspetto, mi attrae.

Quindi, sapreste dire se 'a fortiori' è italiano o latino?

Se 'a fortiori' fosse una frase latina, sapreste spiegare perche' 'a priori' non lo è?

---

So, the question is: Is 'a fortiori' an Italian phrase or a Latin expression? I.e., is 'a fortiori' Italian or Latin?

Should 'a fortiori' be Latin, can anyone explain why 'a priori' is surely Italian?

Comment: Non ho sufficienti argomenti per una risposta, ma credo che siano tutte espressioni latine entrate a far parte dell'italiano specialistico: "a priori" si usa in logica e "a fortiori" dovrebbe essere un'espressione giuridica.

Comment: @martina, per quanto ricordi, credo di avere visto 'a fortiori' anche in scritti non giuridici, e, sempre per quanto ricordi, in quegli scritti era riportato in corsivo, come se non fosse italiano; sicche' la domanda.

Comment: D'accordo, però si usano nell'italiano sostanzialmente come espressione latina di cui non si fa diretta traduzione. Ecco perché si trovano spesso in corsivo. Per deficit, non essendo un'espressione ma una singola parola, credo che sia un diretto inserimento in italiano da latino e si usa proprio così.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si potrebbe pensare di estendere il ragionamento ad una miriade di parole di origine straniera: *ketchup* è una parola italiana? E *ping-pong*? *Barbeque*? *Culotte*?
Il caso latino è però speciale, per l'ovvio motivo che il grosso del vocabolario italiano è evoluto da lì.

Il confine della lingua, sia riguardo al vocabolario che alla grammatica, è dettato dall'uso. Dizionari e ricerche bibliografiche sono dunque i due migliori modi per discriminare le parole (e le locuzioni, ovviamente) italiane da quelle che non hanno compiuto il passaggio.

Nello specifico, la locuzione *a fortiori* è praticamente in disuso nel parlato comune, e non mi stupirei se i dizionari la includessero tra i latinismi o addirittura la escludessero (non ho purtroppo le risorse per effettuare ora una tale ricerca).
Al contrario, *a priori* ha per secoli goduto di grande popolarità, e pertanto si può considerare pienamente parte della lingua italiana.
Una [ricerca su Google books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20priori,a%20fortiori&year_start=1200&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,a%20priori;,c0;.t1;,a%20fortiori;,c0) mostra chiaramente lo sbilanciamento tra le due espressioni.

Comment: "è praticamente in disuso nel parlato comune", dipende con chi parli attenzione e dal luogo anche (fai un salto in un decente dip di filosofia, penso anche di giurisprudenza o di scienze politiche o di lettere, o tra amici di questo, questi, che lo usano quando occorre quasi tutti, in certe tematiche di matematica anche).

Comment: Dalle mie parti in Sicilia lo capiscono ed io lo uso quando serve, lo usavo giá dalla scuole superiori, e non mi è mai capitato di incontrare una persona che non sapesse cosa "a fortiori" potesse significare. Penso ti occorre qualche dato in dettaglio e forse più regionale per dire "praticamente in disuso nel parlato comune"...

Answer (score 0):

Sul [dizionario Treccani online](http://www.treccani.it/)  [a fortiori](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/a-fortiori/) è riportata come appartenente alla lingua italiana con caratteristiche simili alla già citata [a priori](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/a-priori/).

Quindi le due espressioni secondo la treccani sono equivalenti.

Io credo che questa domanda sia in realtà un caso specifico di una domanda più ampia, vale a dire: in quali casi parole "di importazione" possono dirsi italiane, e quando straniere, pur essendo entrambe usate correntemente nella lingua italiana?

Ho provato a riportare questa questione in questa domanda: [Quando si può dire che una parola appartiene alla lingua italiana?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/quando-si-puo-dire-che-una-parola-appartiene-alla-lingua-italiana)

Comment: "con caratteristiche simili", "sono equivalenti".. in che senso un attimo? Puoi specificare per favore!? Secondo Treccani se cerchi l´una e l´altra leggi due cose distinte, se hai studiato latino puó saperlo giá di tuo!